# In GSL, is any function for non-linear curve fitting

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, gsl, nonlinear-functions

I'm searching for curve fitting(non-linear) function in GSL. 
Like we have Polyfit function in Matlab, is there any same type function in GSL also ?

Thanks

Comment: i searched but could not get

Comment: how about this link: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression#C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GSL,you have both [linear fitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Least_002dSquares-Fitting.html) and [non linear fitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Nonlinear-Least_002dSquares-Fitting.html).

Although its usage can be a bit tough for the newcomer.